# Notepad++ EOL conversion difficulties from UNIX to windows. How to ensure it stays converted?

Tags: notepad++, conversion

I have a .txt file which is in a UNIX/OSX format when it should be in windows.

I have tried to convert it in Notepad++ through Edit>EOL Conversion>Windows format. However when I convert it in notepad++ and save it, when I reopen it, it has jumped back into the wrong format.

Has anyone got any idea how I can convert it to windows and make it stay that way?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell what you are looking for is [the tool unix2dos](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos).

Tofrodos has a downloadable Windows console executable in a [zip archive](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/).

I would use this tool on your documents - that should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this bug once, but then on later tests it worked again. What always worked was using the function "Save copy as" after the conversion. Maybe that is of help.